# BackgroundWorker DisconnectedContext

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

i have the folling code:

```
public static Emgu.CV.Capture _capture;
public static DispatcherTimer _timer;
```

```
_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
_timer.Interval = _settings.camera_interval;
_timer.Tick += ProcessFrame;
```

```
BacgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker
{
    WorkerReportsProgress = true,
    WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
};

_bw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
    // Initialize the device in background
    _capture = new Capture();
};

_bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    _capture.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,
        _settings.camera_height);
    _capture.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,
        _settings.camera_width);
    Brightness = _capture
        .GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS);

    Contrast = _capture
        .GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST);

    // Get images from camera
    _timer.Start();
};

_bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

```
 public override void CleanUp()
 {
     _timer.Stop();            
     _bw.Dispose();
     if (_capture != null) _capture.Dispose();
 }
```

the app work fine but when i close the app throw me: `Message: Context0x23754b0' Disconnected. ...` **how to fix this problem?**

Answer (score 2):

This is a COM related error, it no doubt happens because you create the Capture object on the background thread.  A COM object has thread affinity, once the thread that creates it stops running, the COM object is dead and cannot be used anymore.  Trying to use it anyway produces the warning.

That this doesn't occur in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler is quite remarkable, this must be buried inside the OpenCV or Emgu plumbing in a non-obvious way.  That certainly doesn't mean it couldn't occur some day.  You'll need to re-think this, it doesn't make much sense to only create the object on the worker and have everything else run on the UI thread.  Do everything on the worker, including the disposing.  Or none of it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this would have something to do with your camera capture library and how it potentially uses unmanaged resources.

I'd start by commenting all the code out of your `RunWorkerCompleted` to see if the message still happens. If it doesn't, then it's caused by one or more of the `GetCaptureProperty` calls. I suspect it won't though.

I see in the [documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/18b6eba7-f18b-fa87-8bf2-2acff68988cb.htm) of Egmu.CV.Capture that there is a `Capture.DisposeObject()` method that talks about releasing the captured object. My guess is that after you instantiate `_capture` and you do what you need to do, you have to do a clean-up.  I'd suggest that after your `ProcessFrame` finishes (or on exit of your application) that you try calling `_capture.DisposeObject()` to see if that cleans up and exits gracefully.

**Edit:**

If all else fails, the approach I would suggest is comment out as much of your code as you can to get to the point where you can exit the program without it throwing an Exception. Then, comment in parts of code until you can locate exactly what gets created or run that will eventually cause your exception on exit. Once you can localize that, you'll have a better idea how to fix it.

Comment: I forgot the CleanUp Method. i'l write in question

Comment: @rkmax, Just as a good practice, I would `Dispose` in reverse order of creation and then try the explicit `Capture.DisposeObject()` method. Oh, and I would remove the `static` modifier from those fields...that could be the problem, actually.

Comment: @rkmax, if they don't have to be `static` then don't make them static. I've also edited my answer with additional suggestions.

Comment: i've commented code from `RunWorkerComplete` and still I get the same error

Comment: I have followed the last tip, I have commented all the code and all I did was `_bw.DoWork += (s, e) => { _capture = new Capture(); }` but the problem persists

Comment: @rkmax, well that's what my answer suspected. Perhaps try running the capture outside of the BackgroundWorker and look into the documentation so see the exact clean-up methods.

Comment: The application works perfectly without the BackgroundWorkers, I wanted too initialize the window and display a message "Initializing device ..."

Comment: @rkmax in that case I think you either do all or none of your capture work in DoWork.